# javascript setTimeout() not waiting, even after calling as an anonymous function

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm having a problem with setTimeout(), it doesn't seem to be waiting to call the function. Firstly i was using it like this:

```
function function1(driver){
  driver.get(secondaryUrl);
}

driver.get(initialUrl);
setTimeout(function1, 3000, driverInstance);
```

This was not working, it would just skip the delay. So i looked it up and apparently wrapping the function as an anonymous function would fix it. So I tried this:

```
function function1(driver){
  driver.get(secondaryUrl);
}

setTimeout(function(){ function1(driverInstance)}, 3000);
```

But this would do the same, just skip the delay and navigate to the second URL as soon as the first is loaded. Can anyone help me with a fix? Thanks

Comment: The second example is working as expected.

Comment: That's the point of *asynchrony* - it doesn't wait until the action happens, it only schedules it to happen somewhen in the future and then returns immediately.

Comment: I've read on numerous posts that if i wrapped it as an anonymous function it would wait before executing

Comment: Are you saying that in your first snippet the `function1` is called immediately? That shouldn't happen, but notice that `driver.get` is called immediately with the `initialUrl`

Comment: @Harvey: And it does: https://jsfiddle.net/m52sctqc/ . FWIW, it doesn't matter how the function is created. All that matters is that you pass a function to `setTimeout`.

Comment: both examples should work fine no skipping delay , please provide a codepen / jsbin of what you are trying to do .

Comment: hmm, the code seems to work in JSFiddle, but not as a nodeJS script. @FelixKling 's jsfiddle is an exact representation of what im trying, its just acting differently in node

Comment: Works the same in Node: https://repl.it/M8ZO. Please post a [mcve] otherwise we are probably not going to be able to help you.

Comment: @HarveyLewis I don't see how is that possible , please include you node version as well as the file you trying to run .

Answer (score 0):

Remove the third parameter from this:

```
setTimeout(function1, 3000, driverInstance);
```

It should be:

```
setTimeout(function () {
    function1(driverInstance)
}, 3000);
```

Comment: I need to pass the parameter through the function though?

Comment: Why should the third parameter be removed? That's how you pass arguments.

Comment: This is still skipping the wait time and executing the function straight away

Comment: So you are saying the OP should do exactly what they are already doing (their second example) ?

Comment: @FelixKling neither of the examples call `function1` or the anon function immediately , what is "OP" ?

Comment: @aeid: *"neither of the examples call function1 or the anon function immediately"* [It used to](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46718547/revisions). *"what is "OP""* See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/256420#256420

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand you correctly, because there is missing variables declaration in your example.
I assume you create object in JS with some method. And the you wish to call this method twice with some delay between. If so then code like this below should work. I've replaced `get` method into `processUrl`.

```
var url1 = 'http://something';
var url2 = 'http://another';

function Driver( url ) {
  this.processUrl = function( url ) {
    // some logic with URL
    console.log( url );
  }
}

var driver = new Driver()

driver.processUrl( url1 );

function fun1( instance ) {
  instance.processUrl( url2 )
}

setTimeout(fun1, 3000, driver);
```

or even simpler solution without using additional function:

```
var url1 = 'http://something';
var url2 = 'http://another';

function Driver( url ) {
  this.processUrl = function( url ) {
    // some logic with URL
    console.log( url );
  }
}

var driver = new Driver()

driver.processUrl( url1 );
setTimeout( driver.processUrl, 3000, url2 );
```

What is important here: lack of parentheses `()`. When you add parentheses at the end of function name it will immediately invoke function when code is process. You need to provide **reference** to function which should be invoked after 3 seconds.